# How to run indiviual file on CodeLite

Tags: c++, codelite

Can we make individual files in codelite and run them not in the project and How to make separate individual files in codelite

Comment: You might want to avoid spending much time on this question. Only the simplest toy programs warrant being in only one file, so you should quickly find yourself moving on to multiple-file projects. It might be a better use of your time to learn how to compile a single file from the command line, rather than through an IDE like CodeLite. (The exact command depends on your compiler, but something simple like `gcc sourcefile.cpp -o runme` is probably adequate.)

Answer (score 1):

Actually codelite is a project-based ide and there is no way to run individual files on it. If you want to run individual files then use a text editor and run it via command prompt or use code:: blocks ide it has an option to run individual files.